# Где ошибка в цикле?

Tags: php, циклы

Мне нужно что бы после лимита значений(то есть ,когда больше 4х li),заново выводился ul, уже со следующими значениями li.Сделал как-то так ,но естественно не правильно.:

```
for ($i=4; $i <= count($tour_incl); $i+4) { 
       $i -= 1;
       $u_count=$i-4;
       for ($j=$u_count; $j < $i; $j++) { 
           echo '<ul class="list-ok" style="margin-top:50px; display:inline-block;">';

           echo '<li style="padding-left: 14px;margin-left: 15px;">' . $tour_incl[$j] . '</li>';                                            
           echo '</ul>';
        }
}
```

Comment: $tour_incl в данном случае =8

Comment: А ДВА-то цикла зачем? одного достаточно, с единичным шагом... `li` выводить безусловно, а `ul` и `/ul` - в зависимости от остатка от деления `i` на 4...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно просто разбить массив на части с помощью `array_chunk()`, и далее в цикле формировать строку, объединяя элементы массива с помощью `join()`:

```
$tour_incl = array(
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
);

array_map(function($a){
    echo '<ul><li>' . join('</li><li>', $a) . '</li></ul>';
}, array_chunk($tour_incl, 4));
```

Результат:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, идеально!